# How to use jQuery functions to navigate between past and future months?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a simple javascript calendar which has to be able to navigate between the past and future months. I used the switch statement to display the month(String) and the year(integer) which is working fine. I have two buttons which you click, you can either go back to the previous month or go forth to the next month. I want the months to display as strings. Instead I'm getting just an integer for the previous and next month only.

index.html

```
<body onload="myCalendar()">


<div class="container">
<i class="prev-month fa fa-chevron-left fa-3x"></i> <i class="next-month fa fa-chevron-right fa-3x"></i>
<br>
<div class="month-year text-center"><h3></h3></div>
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tr>
    <th>S</th>
    <th>M</th>
    <th>T</th>
    <th>W</th>
    <th>T</th>
    <th>F</th>
    <th>S</th>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>


<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
</tr>


<tr>
    <td class="today">9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>28</td>
    <td>29</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>30</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>



</table>




</div>
```

main.js

```
$(function myCalendar() {

var today = 'today';
var d = new Date();
var month = d.getUTCMonth();
var day = d.getUTCDate();
var year = d.getUTCFullYear();
var nextMonth = month + 1;
var prevMonth = month - 1;


// Displays the current month in Strings and the actual year 
switch(month) {
    case 0: $('.month-year').append('<h3> ' + 'January' + ' ' +  year + ' </h3>' ); break;
    case 1: $('.month-year').append('<h3> ' + 'February' + ' ' + year + ' </h3>' ); break;
    case 2: $('.month-year').append('<h3> ' + 'March' + ' ' + year + ' </h3>' ); break;
    case 3: $('.month-year').append('<h3> ' + 'April' + ' ' + year + ' </h3>' ); break;
    case 4: $('.month-year').append('<h3> ' + 'May' + ' ' + year + ' </h3>' ); break;
    case 5: $('.month-year').append('<h3> ' + 'June' + ' ' + year + ' </h3>' ); break;
    case 6: $('.month-year').append('<h3> ' + 'July' + ' ' + year + ' </h3>' ); break;
    case 7: $('.month-year').append('<h3> ' + 'August' + ' ' + year + ' </h3>' ); break;
    case 8: $('.month-year').append('<h3> ' + 'September' + ' ' + year + ' </h3>' ); break;
    case 9: $('.month-year').append('<h3> ' + 'October' + ' ' + year + ' </h3>' ); break;
    case 10: $('.month-year').append('<h3> ' + 'November' + ' ' + year + ' </h3>' ); break;
    case 11: $('.month-year').append('<h3> ' + 'December' + ' ' + year + ' </h3>' ); break;
    default:
    break;

}

//Navigation Buttons



$('.prev-month').click(function(){
    $('.month-year').html(prevMonth);
    counter--;

});

$('.next-month').click(function(){
    $('.month-year').html(nextMonth);
    counter++;
});
```

Comment: Can you provide some fiddles of your sample?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hjqy5ebx/12/  

For some reason on JFiddle, the month and year aren't displaying except locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [updated your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o6fap41z/2/) to work in any environment.

1) Moved `<body onload="myCalendar()">` into main javascript tag because those scope schemes don't work.

2) Moved `jquery.min.js` to be loaded first, prior to `bootstrap.min.js`.

Your code has some problems and before pointing out what those are, I strongly recommend you to use some calendar libraries like [jQuery UI datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/), [Pikaday](https://dbushell.com/Pikaday/) because there're actually quite a good amount of thing that you should consider when you build a **"simple"** calendar.

#### 1. Undefined variable

There's no `counter` variable in the code, which results in `Uncaught ReferenceError: counter is not defined`.

#### 2. Wrong HTML

You're putting some integers (`prevMonth` and `nextMonth`) into your `.month-year` element, which is the exact result you've described.

### Updated

I [updated my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o6fap41z/5/) with some comments.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Global date.
    var d = new Date();

  function myCalendar() {
    // month, day, year change when myCalendar is called based on global date.
    var month = d.getUTCMonth();
    var day = d.getUTCDate();
    var year = d.getUTCFullYear();

    // Displays the current month in Strings and the actual year 
    switch(month) {
      case 0: $('.month-year').append('<h3> ' + 'January' + ' ' +  year + ' </h3>' ); break;
      case 1: $('.month-year').append('<h3> ' + 'February' + ' ' + year + ' </h3>' ); break;
      case 2: $('.month-year').append('<h3> ' + 'March' + ' ' + year + ' </h3>' ); break;
      case 3: $('.month-year').append('<h3> ' + 'April' + ' ' + year + ' </h3>' ); break;
      case 4: $('.month-year').append('<h3> ' + 'May' + ' ' + year + ' </h3>' ); break;
      case 5: $('.month-year').append('<h3> ' + 'June' + ' ' + year + ' </h3>' ); break;
      case 6: $('.month-year').append('<h3> ' + 'July' + ' ' + year + ' </h3>' ); break;
      case 7: $('.month-year').append('<h3> ' + 'August' + ' ' + year + ' </h3>' ); break;
      case 8: $('.month-year').append('<h3> ' + 'September' + ' ' + year + ' </h3>' ); break;
      case 9: $('.month-year').append('<h3> ' + 'October' + ' ' + year + ' </h3>' ); break;
      case 10: $('.month-year').append('<h3> ' + 'November' + ' ' + year + ' </h3>' ); break;
      case 11: $('.month-year').append('<h3> ' + 'December' + ' ' + year + ' </h3>' ); break;
      default:
      break;

    }
  };

    // On window load, call myCalendar first to draw today's calendar.
  myCalendar();

  // Navigation Buttons
  $('.prev-month').click(function(){
    // On .prev-month click, first empty .month-year container, set global date's month to the previous one, and call myCalendar to update the month / year title.
    $('.month-year').empty();
    d.setUTCMonth(d.getUTCMonth() - 1);
    myCalendar();
  });

  $('.next-month').click(function(){
    // On .next-month click, first empty .month-year container, set global date's month to the next one, and call myCalendar to update the month / year title.
    $('.month-year').empty();
    d.setUTCMonth(d.getUTCMonth() + 1);
    myCalendar();
  });
});
```

Comment: I had the variable but deleted by mistake. It's been added now. Still not working.

Comment: Yes it won't work. I just pointed out the very basic stuffs on what's going on your code. The calendar thing can't be this simple. First of all, have you ever noticed that your code doesn't have an algorithm to draw different `<table>`(days) for different months?

Comment: I was going to get to that as soon as I figured out what I needed to do to make my buttons work.

Comment: Solved it. Thanks!